# how to make mysql derived table use index

Tags: mysql, derived-table

MySQL version 5.6.33

I have two tables (**files** & **details**) to inner join

table **files**, has an index called **idx_record**(record_id)

table **details**, has an index called **idx_end_org_record**(end_at, org_id, record_id)

```
explain
SELECT
    id as file_id,
    record_id,
    recording_path
FROM `files`
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `details`.`record_id`
    FROM `details` 
    WHERE `details`.`org_id` IN (6231, 6232, 6233, 6234) 
    AND (`details`.`end_at` BETWEEN '2017-05-31 16:00:00' AND '2017-06-13 16:00:00') 
    ORDER BY end_at desc
) as b
    on `files`.record_id = b.record_id 
WHERE (file_name IS NOT NULL )
LIMIT 30
```

Output as below

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref              | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>   | ALL   | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL             | 3844632 | Using where              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | files        | ref   | idx_record         | idx_record         | 5       | b.record_id      |       1 | Using where              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | details      | range | idx_end_org_record | idx_end_org_record | 11      | NULL             | 3844632 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

As you can see, the `<derived2>` table is not using any index, making this query take almost 1 second to finish.

Any help is appreciated!

---

Besides, removing `WHERE (file_name IS NOT NULL )` in the query doesn't make any difference.

And in mysql 5.7, this problem doesn't even exist, but currently I'm trying to solve this in 5.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the point of the subquery.  In particular, the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is meaningless.  If you write the query as a direct join between the two tables, then the optimizer should be able to take advantage of an index on the join column:

```
SELECT
id as file_id,
record_id,
recording_path
FROM files f
INNER JOIN details d
    ON f.record_id = d.record_id AND
       d.org_id IN (6231, 6232, 6233, 6234) AND
       d.end_at BETWEEN '2017-05-31 16:00:00' AND '2017-06-13 16:00:00'
WHERE f.file_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY <some column>    -- it doesn't make sense most of the time to use LIMIT
LIMIT 30                  -- without ORDER BY
```

Adding an index on `record_id`, `org_id`, and `end_at` in the `details` table, and on `file_name` in the `files` table, should give you some peformance improvements.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Then let's add some meaning here :-)

Comment: 1. This is a inner join, so the subquery does make sense: it find out all files not only with not-null file_name, but also whose details meet some conditions.

Comment: 2. Thanks for your advice, but removing `ORDER BY` doesn't help much, only saved like 100ms. I have tried to change column order in the index, and it turned out that idx_end_org_record(org_id, end_at, record_id) in table details save nearly 300ms. The difference between these two index is that the latter make the `rows` in explain output 10 times less. However, it still not use index in the `<derived2>` table, using index will make sense, isn't it?

Comment: Did you actually use my full answer, or did you just do a few hodgepodge things to your original query?

Comment: Sorry, I see your point now. In your query, you move the conditions into the on clause, it seems remove the derived table in optimizer

Comment: Ohmy, this is really awesome, putting conditions in ON clause, can avoid generating derived table! (Even subquery itself execute very fast, derived table can be a problem)

Comment: Would you mind if I ask a related question that, when to use subquery while I can put these conditions all in ON clause like you taught me to ?

Comment: You don't need to even put them in the `ON` clause I believe in this case.  You could have also put them into the `WHERE` clause.  If you have a substantially different question, then ask a new one.